# stopPropagation on (tap) event Ionic 2

Tags: android, ios, ionic2, click, tap

On Ionic 2, event.stopPropagation() doesn't exist for `(tap)` event:

[image]

I was using `(click)` because we had only the Android version, but with IOS the `(click)` event doesn't works properly and `(tap)` yes.

We need `stopPropagation` because we have a list of audios where each item, when clicked it must reproduce the corresponding audio, therefore has the event `(tap)= play(audio)` but these items at once have an icon to download and another to play . When you click the download icon, we need `stopPropagation()` so that the parent container event is not executed and can download instead of playing.

So, any solution to stopProgation?

Comment: Try like this. `<ion-item tappable (click)="playOrPause($event)">`. It works for me.

Comment: Thank you, I will try with tappable attribute.